# How to store Vim tabstop settings in the file?

Tags: vim

I need different tab widths for different files when using Vim. Is there a way to store this information in the file, and let Vim apply the setting automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what fits your situation you could look into customizing the filetype plugins (if you want tabstop settings by filetype) or enable [modelines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6) and accept the accompanying security risks if the settings are specific to individual files.

For the filetype approach, as an example I have the following in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
setlocal expandtab softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

Comment: Modelines is what I was looking for. Thanks!